# wordpress url customization to make it more seo friendly url

Tags: wordpress, url, for-loop, customization, store

Hi I have a website having URL: http://www.couponvenue.in/store/myntra/ how can I change the URL to http://www.couponvenue.in/myntra.html. I have tried to do with .htacess code which I have found in the internet after doing some google on it.

The .htaccess code is shown below:

RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ /store/$1 [L]

The above rule states that if I will type the URL: http://www.couponvenue.in/myntra.html, this would try to open the URL: http://www.couponvenue.in/store/myntra

I have tried it in core php file and it was working fine, but when I use the same code in wordpress site http://www.couponvenue.in/store/myntra/ it was giving me 404 error please suggest how can I make it run in my wordpress site too.

I am using WordPress 4.0.1 using Clipper theme. The current setting for permalink is set as "Post name" showing my store URL as http://www.couponvenue.in/store/myntra/ but when I set the permalink to default setting it shows my store URL: as http://www.couponvenue.in/?stores=myntra.

I have tried the plugin WordPress SEO by Yoast but no suscess

Please suggest how can I be able to create URL like http://www.couponvenue.in/myntra.html instead of  http://www.couponvenue.in/store/myntra/ OR http://www.couponvenue.in/?stores=myntra Also please let me know what is wrong in the rule RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ /store/$1 [L]

Comment: do you use Woocommerce? do you really need to remove it or rename it would be enough?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this structure in the permalinks options :
`%postname%.html`

Just for information the url http://www.couponvenue.in/store/myntra is more better for SEO.

The seo friendly must be like this : `/%post_id%/%postname%/`

Answer (score 0):

I would try this option first before taking on any .httaccess file changes - I think this gets you where you are trying to go.

You likely have the "Myntra" as a "child" page to the "parent page" "Store" - and to switch it back should be pretty simple.

If you go into you the Myntra page in the WP editor (or any other page that you want to change in a similar way) and look at the "Page Attributes" box on the right side column of your screen - if it is not there - go to the top of that page editor and click on the "Screen Option" tab - which will give you some choices to add additional page options in your Page Editor Dashboard.

Once you find the "Page Attributes" box - make your "Myntra" page have "(no parent)" and update the page.  This should move that page url to:

www.Couponvenue.in/Myntra

You may also want to now check that it is still found in the menu drop down on your home page - for that go to your "Appearance" tab on the main dashboard menu options on the left of the WP Dashboard - then click Menus and you can fix what is likely your Main Menu to still pull that page in it's new location - if that didn't already automatically update.

I would also add that for SEO purposes you are correct in thinking that all things being equal that www.Couponvue.com/Myntra does target the keyword "Myntra" more effectively than www.Couponvue.in/Store/Myntra.

Hope that helps!